# Rename files in folder

Tags: file-rename

I have thousands of files, I want to remove part of files name. 
For example:

```
Agu-1_9942_quant.sf
Aiell-1_9646_quant.sf
```

Should be converted to

```
9942_quant.sf
9646_quant.sf
```

I am trying rename function (`rename 's/_//g' *.sf`) but unable to get desired results. Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: What platform/shell is this? Please tag the question appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is bash scripting:

```
for elem in ./*
do
if echo $elem | grep '_'; then
    elem_new=$(echo $elem | cut -d '_' -f 1 --complement)
    mv $elem $elem_new
fi
done
```